Mensaje de campo obligatorio en Lista Desplegable en aplicación MVC con Razor
Hice un curso de programación en c#, estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación mvc.
De acuerdo al modelo desarrollado en el curso, la aplicación hace uso de Patrón de Repositorios y Dapper.
En mi modelo tengo el siguiente campo:
[Display(Name = "Inventariado x", Description = "Inventariado")] 
public int IdPersInv { get; set; }

El campo IdPersinv se refiere al id del personal que hizo el último inventario, pero no necesariamente contiene información, es decir, en muchos casos se desconoce dicho personal.
En mi vista puse el siguiente código para crear una lista desplegable:
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdPersInv, SelectList)ViewBag.UsuarioList, "Seleccione Usuario", new { id="cboPersInv", @class = "form-control" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPersInv, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

En el controlador puse el siguiente código para jalar la data que llenará el DropDownList:
ClsOperaciones<Usuarios> usuarios = new ClsOperaciones<Usuarios>(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SoporteConnection"].ToString());

ViewBag.UsuarioList = new SelectList(usuarios.GetDataSP("sp_Usuarios"), "IdUsuario", "Usuario");

En el Repositorio el ClsOperaciones tiene el siguiente código:
public List<T> GetDataSP(string proc)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
    {
        var datos = connection.Query<T>(proc, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        return datos;
    }
}

La lista desplegable funciona bien, el problema es cuando no hay información en ese campo y no se realiza seleccion en el DropDownList, al intentar guardar, me sale un mensaje que dice que ese campo es obligatorio, pero no deseo seleccionar nada porque aún no se ha hecho verificación de ese equipo, o bien se hizo pero no hay registro, y como se puede apreciar, en el modelo no se ha consignado que el campo sea obligatorio.
A qué se debe que me pida obligatoriamente que haga una selección en el DropDownList?,
Hay alguna forma de evitar tener que seleccionar algo en el DropDownList?
Gracias por la atención.

Podrias especificar quien te da el error de campo obligatorio? porque ese campo siempre tiene un valor (es un int, y no lo pusiste como nullable) por lo tanto, siempre viene algo...

Partamos con lo básico: Un select siempre tiene un option seleccionado, lo digo porque tú dices que:

no se realiza selección

Lo cual es imposible. Lo que se hace típicamente es dejar el primer option (puede ser cualquiera) con un value en blanco, esto funciona para la validación desde el cliente:


<form>
 <select required>
   <option value="">Nulo</option>
 </select>
 <button>Guardar</button>
</form>



E igualmente funciona para la validación en el servidor con ASP.net, la cual típicamente se realiza con ModelState.IsValid
La validación desde el ModelState realiza una comprobación de tipos y como algo vacío no puede ser convertido a un int no pasará la validación
La solución es bastante simple y lógica si lo piensas, dado que IdPersInv es un campo que puede o no puede estar presente, debería ser del tipo int? (nuleable int)
[Display(Name = "Inventariado x", Description = "Inventariado")] 
public int? IdPersInv { get; set; }


@gbianchi dice en un comentario:

...ese campo siempre tiene un valor (es un int, y no lo pusiste como
nullable) por lo tanto, siempre viene algo.

Es un buen punto. Pero no hay que confundir el ModelState con el "Modelo".
El modelo llega como texto al servidor (ya sea por formulario o JSON), el servidor parsea esos datos y los convierte en un Objeto C# y se lo pasa al argumento del controller/Action:
private async Task<IActionResult> Crear(Usuario usuario)
//              Esto es un objeto parseado ↗

Y C# cuando paresea instancia un objeto y le asigna sus valores correspondientes (cuando los valores coinciden con el tipo), y como cuando se instancia un objeto las propiedades se inicializan con su default que para el caso de los int es cero, pasa que IdPersInv queda como cero en el modelo parseado.
Es en el momento que va asignando los valores donde se realizan las comprobaciones que quedan en el ModelState
Por este motivo no es necesario pasarle el "Modelo" al ModelState para que lo valide, porque esta operación ya está hecha. Es decir, llegado al controller el "Modelo" y el ModelState están creados y corren por caminos separados.
Por otro lado, si no fuera de esa manera, posiblemente ni se podría acceder a la función del controller/action, ya que el tipo de dato en el argumento podría no corresponder al argumento de la función
